# What should the ownership and file permissions be on catalina.policy?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, catalina

We had the timestamp changed on the file `catalina.policy` to root:root 755.  We're not sure that is correct but can't find an answer via any search engine or `catalina.policy` documentation. Can someone look at theirs and tell us what it is?

Answer (score 0):

- Download Tomcat 7 at here https://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi
- Then unzip.
- Check permission of original file.
- Set your file like previous permission number what you seen.

I am on Windows, the screenshot just helps you imagine the solution better.
[image]

Comment: I didn't know if there file permissions changed during the install (e.g. the install scripts sets them)